# Prototype - get next text input after an HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

I have a javascript object called 'element' of type HTMLInputElement that corresponds to a HTML input text box element on my page.  (Thus, something like `$F('element')` using prototype will return the text of this box).  Is there a way, using prototype and this 'element', for me to access the value of the **next** HTML input text box in the DOM after 'element'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Element.next`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/next) with a CSS rule:

```
$('element').next('input[type=text]');
```

Comment: This one works only if the input elements are on the same level (they are siblings) but not for the whole DOM

Comment: Yes, I assumed that he was looking for the next `input` sibling, but if it's not the case the OP should post some markup...

Comment: Sorry about that; I should have mentioned that my elements were not siblings. Thanks, CMS, for your answer.  I was able to use it in conjunction with 'down' to get what I was looking for: $F(element.next('div').down('input[type=text]'))